# When is it necessary to check if a subscriber is subscribed prior to calling onNext() and onError()?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

Consider the following example, it creates an `Observable` that wraps another API that produces `Widgets`

```java
public Observable<Widget> createWidgetObservable() {

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Widget>() {

            @Override
            public void call(final Subscriber<? super Widget> subscriber) {
                WidgetCreator widgetCreator = new WidgetCreator();
                widgetCreator.setWidgetCreatorObserver(new WidgetCreator.WidgetCreatorObserver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onWidgetCreated(Widget widget) {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onNext(widget);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onWidgetError(Throwable e) {
                        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
                            subscriber.onError(e);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        });
    }
```

Are the `subscriber.isUnsubscribed()` checks necessary prior to calling `subscriber.onNext()` and `subscriber.onError()`?

If so, are the checks always necessary or does it depend on the composition / subscriber that's using the observable?

Is it best practice to include the checks?

Answer (score 3):

You can use them to narrow the window between an emission and an unsubscription but if you don't have loops, it is unnecessary most of the time. The more important thing is that if an unsubscription happen, you'd have to "unset" the `WidgetCreatorObserver` otherwise it will keep receiving and dropping data and keeping alive every reference it may hold.

```
WidgetCreator widgetCreator = new WidgetCreator();
WidgetCreator.WidgetCreatorObserver wo = new WidgetCreator.WidgetCreatorObserver() {
    @Override
    public void onWidgetCreated(Widget widget) {
        if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            subscriber.onNext(widget);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWidgetError(Throwable e) {
         if (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
             subscriber.onError(e);
         }
    }
}

widgetCreator.setWidgetCreatorObserver(wo);
wo.add(Subscriptions.create(() -> widgetCreator.removeWidgetCreatorObserver(wo)));
```